# Where are the dependency Versions defined in build gradle (app) of Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I imported a project from GitHub of Universal Music Player - Google Sample.
I can't find where the Versions of dependencies are defined in here.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer

This is where I imported the project from

dependencies {
    implementation project(':media')

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"

implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$androidx_app_compat_version"
implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:$androidx_version"
implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$androidx_version"

implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$constraint_layout_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$arch_lifecycle_version"

// Glide dependencies
implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glide_version"
kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glide_version"
```

}

I was expecting def version name, but can't seem to figure out where it is in the Google sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The versions are defined in the `build.gradle` of the project root folder.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        // App SDK versions.
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        minSdkVersion = 19
        targetSdkVersion = 28

        // Dependency versions.
        arch_lifecycle_version = '2.0.0'
        constraint_layout_version = '1.1.3'
        exoplayer_version = '2.9.1'
        glide_version = '4.8.0'
        gms_strict_version_matcher_version = '1.0.3'
        gradle_version = '3.1.4'
        gson_version = '2.8.5'
        kotlin_version = '1.3.10'
        androidx_version = '1.0.0'
        androidx_app_compat_version = '1.0.2'
        test_runner_version = '1.1.0'
    }
}
```